# possible to safely force exit from ansible-playbook run?

Tags: ansible

If i'm running an Ansible playbook against many servers and for some reason i spot an error in the play that i feel needs the run to be stopped immediately. At the moment i mash Ctrl+C and it abruptly stops. But this feels nasty and risks leaving the servers in a inconsistent state depending on the task type and what it's doing.

I don't really know what Ctrl+C does while Ansible is running a play on several servers but it looks like it just terminates dead on the local console.. i assume also on remote server.

Is there a signal that can be sent to Ansible to request that it completes running the playbook on the servers its currently working on, lets say fork 5 is used, but does not to proceed further with remaining servers in the inventory list.

Thanks
fLo

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such built-in feature. You might be able to [create your own strategy plugin](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_strategies.html) which queries an external source which defines which hosts should be processed next - or fail. In its simplest form you could copy the [linear strategy](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/strategy/linear.py) and additionally check in the code if a certain file exists. If you want to stop execution, manually create the file.

<sub>I have not worked with strategy plugins yet, but from my understanding this should work.</sub>